# Are へ and に interchangeable in these cases?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-へ

I'm just starting to learn Japanese.
I do not quite understand one of the uses of the captioned particles.
I've learned that に refers to the location of the destination, and へ refers to the direction of the destination. But my friend told me they are interchangeable and に is colloquial and へ is for writing. If yes, in below cases are they interchangeable?

> 1. 川の向こう**へ**渡る橋は一つしかありませんでした。
> 2. 友達とレストラン**へ**行きます。
> 3. 来月国**へ**帰ります。

Will the meanings be different if へ is changed to に? If yes, what difference will there be?

Comment: Here's our [chat log about へ and に](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/conversation/e-ni).  I wrote a bit, but you might want to pay special attention to Schoko's messages, as she's a native speaker and I'm a learner.  (I also tried my best to write an answer.)

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41787/the-%e3%81%ab%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-construction-and-particles

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use へ or に more or less interchangeably in your examples without any real change in meaning, but に is probably the more common choice.

> 1a. 川の向こう**へ**渡る橋は一つしかありませんでした。
>   1b. 川の向こう**に**渡る橋は一つしかありませんでした。
>
> 2a. 友達とレストラン**へ**行きます。
>   2b. 友達とレストラン**に**行きます。
>
> 3a. 来月国**へ**帰ります。
>   3b. 来月国**に**帰ります。

Even if you use へ instead of に, you wouldn't be returning *in the direction* of your home country next month, you'd be returning *to* your home country.  You most likely wouldn't be going *in the direction of* a restaurant with your friend, you'd be going *to* a restaurant with your friend.

Sometimes you find explanations online saying something like "に indicates a destination while へ indicates a direction of motion".  While it's true that へ can indicate a direction rather than a destination, this isn't the whole story.  **The particle へ can also indicate the *endpoint* of motion**, and it often does.  When it does, へ and に have a lot of overlap.

In fact, when I check 明鏡国語辞典, I find:

> ①《移動や伝達など方向性をもつ述語とともに使って》
>   　㋐《方向を表す体言に付いて》移動の方向を表す。
>   　　「一路西へ向かう」「右へ右へと回る」「こっちへ来い」「海の方へ飛んでいく」
>   　㋑《**地点を表す**体言に付いて》**到達点を表す**。
>   　　「頂上へたどり着く」「故郷へ帰る」「池へコイを放つ」「荷物をロッカーへ入れる」

As you can see, monolingual dictionaries also list the "endpoint of motion" meaning for へ.  Take a look at the examples under ①㋑:

1. Do you imagine finally reaching the summit of the mountain after a long journey, or do you imagine finally reaching *in the direction of* the mountaintop?  What would that even mean?
2. Do you imagine returning to your hometown, or do you imagine returning *in the direction* of your hometown?  The latter doesn't really make sense, does it?
3. Do you imagine putting your luggage in a locker, or do you imagine putting your luggage *in the direction* of the locker?  Again, the latter is probably not what it means.

Sometimes へ is very much like に.

---

In general, when both へ and に can be used with the same meaning, に is more common.  This is particularly true in speech, where に is significantly more common than へ.

So yes, it's true that へ is used more often in writing.  Part of this is because of への and へと:

1. The sequence への is often used because ＊にの is ungrammatical:

   > 東京**への**道　the road to Tōkyō
   >   ＊東京**にの**道　*(ungrammatical)*

   This construction is more common in writing than in speech.
2. And へと is a literary compound particle indicating a spatial (or sometimes non-spatial) goal, so of course in this usage へ appears mainly in writing.

But people certainly say へ as well, just not quite as often.  In speech, へ appears particularly often following certain nouns, for example in そこへ or どこへ.  So your friend's explanation that に is colloquial and へ is for writing isn't quite right.

---

In this answer, the giant asterisk ＊ marks a sequence as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

「に」 being colloquial and 「へ」 being for writing, not really. You can have colloquial writing, for example. I think your friend is mixing *spoken* language with *colloquial* language.

**Spoken** would be the language that comes out in the form of sound. Being **sponken** doesn't automatically implies that it is **colloquial**. You can have **formal**, **polite** spoken language, like people interacting in a business meeting or in a corporate environment. Likewise, you can have **colloquial written** language, like a lot of dialogue in fiction or text messages exchanged between friends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Questions :
1) differences in nuance: could you give examples in English?  
2) spoken vs colloquial writing :  could you also give English examples?

Comment: Just edited the answer, please check it to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks very much! Well explained! A final question,regarding "Using 「へ」 can be more "formal" in the sense", so do you mean these two particles have different tones implied?